# Регулярное выражение по строке за исключением html-тегов

Tags: python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Нужно заменить кавычки `''` и `""` на `«»` в строке, не ломая html-теги.

Нашёл выражение для поиска тегов в строке `<(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^\'">])*>`, но не могу понять, как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы оно работало наоборот не в тегах и искало слова в кавычках снаружи тегов (в тексте между закрывающим и открывающим тегом и снаружи этих тегов).

---

Реализовал в своём проекте

https://github.com/John2013/23_typograf

Файл [/typograf.py](https://github.com/John2013/23_typograf/blob/master/typograf.py)

Comment: `re.sub(r'<[^>]*>|"([^"]*)"', lambda x: "«{}»".format(x.group(1)) if x.group(1) else x.group(0), s)`, но лучше сначала распарсить всё правильно с помощью BeautifulSoup, и использовать `re.sub(r'"([^"]*)"', r'«\1»', text)`

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо, вот так `<(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'|[^\'">])*>|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\'`, пожалуй, будет идеально

Comment: Не, идеально - это с `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Таким образом сами теги тоже удаляются, значит их тоже нужно добавить в группу и вставлять без изменений

Comment: к чему с регулярными выражениями мучаться, если html парсеры есть? [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4279)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Заменить кавычки " на &quot; вне html-тэгов в Питоне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/815027/23044)