# Заменить кавычки " на &quot; вне html-тэгов в Питоне

Tags: html, python, python-3.x

Дайте абстрактную идею, как это можно решить: есть тест + html теги, мне надо что бы кавычки (") которые в тексте а не в тегах, заменились на `&quot;` . Как это можно сделать ? Спасибо!

```html
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-description"> 
<p style="margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 20px; border: 0px; font-variant-numeric: inherit; font-variant-east-asian: inherit; font-stretch: inherit; line-height: 1.8; font-family: Philosopher, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline;"> 
<span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Тройник дымоходный 45° из нержавеющей стали предназначен для отвода отходящих газов в дымоход и обеспечивает возможность чистки и обслуживания дымоходной трубы с отсеканием конденсата. Для исключения попадания конденсата в тройник 45° установлен капельник. Как правило, используется в комлпекте с ревизией либо лейкой. Соединяется между собой и с другими элементами системы дымохода без дополнительного крепления: "труба в трубу". 
</span> 
</p>
```

Comment: Если я буду использовать метод replace то у меня заменяться кавычки которые идут в тегах, или я ошибаюсь ?

Comment: Я бы прогнал это через какой-нибудь html-парсер, а он там сам всё сделает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы в html документе кавычки выводить как `&quot;` (в чём нет необходимости — кавычки в тексте вне html-тэгов вполне легальны), [можно свой formatter указать у BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_str, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify(formatter=lambda t: t.replace('"', '&quot;')))
```

Comment: jfs, спасибо за ответ, все работает. Только не могу который час понять некоторые моменты: 
1. prettify() - метод которые форматирует html страницу в читабельный вид, верно ж? 
2. Так же я не увидел в интернете что бы prettify() принимала аргументы.. 
3. Как formatter отработал тоже не совсем понял( Был бы вам очень благодарен если бы немного пояснили мне новичку. Спасибо !

Comment: @alexshel нажмите на ссылку в ответе, которая вас на страницу с beautifulsoup документацией приведёт, где явно примеры вызова prettify() метода показаны с параметром formatter

Comment: jfs, Спасибо вроде дошло!